# Does the existing processmaker app fully compatible for processmaker 4?

Tags: processmaker

I'm new to processmaker, don't have that much understanding. I found an android app for processmaker in play store. It says that it supports processmaker 3.2+. As I'm learning on processmaker 4, I'm curious that is there any app for processmaker 4 support? Or I want to know if the existing app is fully compatible with processmaker 4? If it's not, can anyone tell me will there be an update for this app to support processmaker 4?

Comment: No, current app is compatible with Processmaker 3.2+
Processmaker 4 is totally different development, it will not work with Processmaker4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProcessMaker Version 4.x is an API first solution with a fully mobile responsive front end.  It does not work with the PM 3.x mobile apps.  The philosophy around mobile apps has changed in PM4.  The API is now designed to make it much easier to create unique mobile experiences.  From what we have seen, mobile requirements come in 2 basic flavors - 1) managers who want to validate and approve, and 2) field workers that want to investigate/record/start cases

For #1, ProcessMaker has an awesome email integration which puts the approvals directly in your email.  The same integration also works for Slack.  We recommend this for those approval type use cases.

For #2, we think it is better either to purpose build the interface you want using our API, or connect to a fieldwork mobile solution.

And the third option is always to use the mobile responsive front end.  However, for the time being, there is no plan to port the existing mobile app to PM4.

Answer (score 1):

I don't work for ProcessMaker, so I am writing this from a user's perspective.

The short answer is No, PM4 doesn't support PM3 apps. However, you can build your apps and use PM4 APIS as the backend powerhouse.

**Not so long answer:**
It's important to note that PM4 is completely different from previous PM versions and the organisation is not shy in expressing that. They have completely changed the architecture and the interactions of each moving part of the software. PM4 components are loosely coupled making it easier to use a bit or all of the components.

Scripts are reusable, screens are reusable, and also approvals have plugins that allow you to approve document flow directly in your inbox. The point is all it takes for you to build an amazing app leveraging PM4 APIS is 90% available. You can check the full docs [here](https://staging-pm4.processmaker.net/api/documentation)

**PM = ProcessMaker